# jdbctemplate not closebale connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, wildfly, jdbctemplate

i have some code

```
@Bean("jdbc")
public JdbcTemplate jdbc(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}

@Bean("dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource(Environment environment) {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    String jndiName = environment.getProperty("dbconnection.jndiName", DEFAULT_DATASOURCE_JNDI_NAME);
    try {
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(jndiName);
    } catch (DataSourceLookupFailureException e) {
        PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        dataSource.setDatabaseName(environment.getProperty("dbconnection.dbname"));
        dataSource.setURL(environment.getProperty("dbconnection.url"));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty("dbconnection.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("dbconnection.password"));
        dataSource.setCurrentSchema(environment.getProperty("dbconnection.dbschema"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

now, using jdbcTemplate in custom Repository method (read only), return list objects

```
 Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        return findByParamsJdbc(arg1, arg2, arg3,
                arg4, arg5,
                arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9,
                arg10, arg11, arg12, connection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(connection)) {
            connection.close();
        }
    } finally {
        if (Objects.nonNull(connection)) {
            if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }
    throw ex999();
```

inside in findByParamsJdbc there are various preparedStatement, 'connection.createArrayOf' and e.t.c.

After some time, the application crashes, server CPU 99% is loaded

**The memory dump showed that the jdbcTemplate does not close the connection and opens a new one every time, Why is this happening ?**

### Class Name                                                                       | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap | Percentage

org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl @ 0x5c438a130                          |          136 |    74,883,816 |     29.72%
|- org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache @ 0x5c4c0b658                   |           32 |    70,764,832 |     28.08%
|- org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator @ 0x5c48177c8                       |           24 |       362,856 |      0.14%
|- org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl @ 0x5c48a2cc8      |           56 |       293,208 |      0.12%
|- org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister @ 0x5c43e3590       |          552 |       235,176 |      0.09%
|- org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl @ 0x5c4812e80|           56 |       182,936 |      0.07%
|- org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister @ 0x5c4535518       |          552 |       119,416 |      0.05%
|- org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister @ 0x5c455d680       |          552 |       118,736 |      0.05%
|- org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister @ 0x5c45697d8       |          552 |       117,576 |      0.05%

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` does close the connection, when used properly. Who wrote the datasource initialization code btw? You try to get a JNDI datasource, but if it fails, you don't even **log** anything and create a non-pooling datasource? Are you using the JNDI or  `PGSimpleDatasource` (which you shouldn't really directly use) when this happens, or do you know it?

Comment: And unless you're working on Java 1.6 or earlier, you'll really want to change that custom repository method of yours to use `try-with-resources`. To make sure you're not accidentally forgetting to close connections.

Comment: It is happening because the code you wrote is wrong. **Never** do `getDataSource().getConnection()` on the `JdbcTemplatez`. You are bypassing the whole template rendering it pretty much useless. You are working around `JdbcTemplate` instead of with it. Use `JdbcTemplate.queryFor*` methods to execute a query and map results, don't use the connection, statements and resultsets.

Comment: @M.Deinum  ok, then how to create 'array' object (createArrayOf) ? if not using getConnection..

Comment: Well how about using a `ConnectionCallback` which provides you with the connection without you having to worry about anything else. Also that fact that you are creating arrays is something you left out of your question although quite relevant. So please add that as well.